# Read lines between specific text and print to file in python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'm new to python and trying to extract lines in the HTML source between two points to Output.txt. But nothing is getting written to the output text file and i've got no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib
sock = urllib.urlopen('http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp')
htmlSource = sock.read()
sock.close()

text_file = open('/home/user/Desktop/Output.txt', 'w')

parsing=False
for line in htmlSource:
    if '<html lang="en-US">' in line:
        parsing = True
    elif '<script src="/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>' in line:
        parsing = False
    if parsing:
        text_file.write("%s\n" % line)

text_file.close()
```

Comment: you can use BeautifulSoup to parse html

Comment: What is your end goal? What are going to do with that part of the HTML page?

Comment: The `for line in htmlSource` reads the `htmlSource` character by character (at least when I try your code) not line by line. Substitute the whole body under the `for line in htmlSource` by just a `print line` and you'll see what I mean.
PS: I agree with @Hackaholic: You might wanna take a look to _BeautifulSoup_

Comment: you want to write to file everything from HTML except script tag right??